Extending sheaves from a locally closed subset
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf over $A$ where $A\subset X$ is locally closed. Godement theorem II.2.9.2 states there exists a unique sheaf $\mathcal{F}_X$ on $X$ whose restriction to $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$ and the restriction to $X\setminus A$ is zero. What is a counterexample to this statemtent?
For example the set $A=\{(x,y) | x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} ,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ an $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, then consider the sheaf of continuous functions over $A$. It is not possible to extend it by zero to $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example the stalk around $(0,0)$ would not be well defined.
Is this the correct idea?

What do you mean by "counterexample to this statement"? The statement is indeed true, and this sheaf is usually denoted by $j_{!}\mathcal{F}$ where $j:A \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion of the locally closed subset $A \subset X$.
In your example, $A$ is open in $X$, and the sheaf would be the sheaf obtained by extending $\mathcal{F}$ by zero outside $A$.

You might be confusing "extending the sheaf by zero outside A" with trying to extending the sections of the sheaf by zeroes, which is indeed not possible for all sections- which is why $j_!(\mathcal{F})$ is only in general a subsheaf of $j_*(\mathcal{F})$.

In the case of sheaf of continuous functions on $A$, the global sections (on X) of the extended sheaf contains only continuous functions supported away from the y-axis, while the sections on $A$ still has all continuous functions over $A$. This is a concrete example for the case when $j_!(\mathcal{F}) \hookrightarrow j_*(\mathcal{F})$ is not surjective. The stalk of $j_!(\mathcal{F})$ is always 0 on any point on $X \backslash A$.
